# How to make a div container extend over the entire HTML page with horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, containers, mathjax

I want that the div container extend over the entire HTML page with horizontal scroll bar, here's a picture that show my problem.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2kXh.jpg)

The div container don't extends when a horizontal scrollbar is necessary.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>
            MathJax.Hub.Config({
                showMathMenu: false,
                jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'],
                displayAlign: "left",
                extensions: ['tex2jax.js','toMathML.js'],
                TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js','noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] },
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js"></script>
        <style>
            .titulo{
                width:100%;
                border-bottom:solid 2px;
                border-color: black;
                background-color:lightgrey;
                font-family:arial;
                font-weight:bold;
                white-space:nowrap;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="titulo">Data</div>
        <div>$$\vec{v_r}=\vec{v_1}+\vec{v_2}\\\vec{v_r}=\left(x_1+x_2,\;y_1+y_2\right)$$</span>
        <div class="titulo">Operations</div>
        <div>$$\vec{v_1}=\left(1000000,\;3000000\right)\\\vec{v_2}=\left(500000,\;2000000\right)\\\vec{v_1}=\left(1000000,\;3000000\right)\\\vec{v_2}=\left(500000,\;2000000\right)\\\vec{v_1}=\left(1000000,\;3000000\right)\\\vec{v_2}=\left(500000,\;2000000\right)\\\vec{v_r}=\left(1000000,\;3000000\right)+\left(500000,\;2000000\right)\\\vec{v_r}=\left(1000000+500000,\;3000000+2000000\right)\\\vec{v_r}=\left(1500000,\;5000000\right)$$</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this? I use MathJax to display math formulas, and I don't know if it is interfering.

Comment: .titulo { position:relative; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }

Comment: .titulo { display: block; } and remove `width: 100%`;

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide `width:100%` for the outer div it take the `100% of the window / document width.` But because of your 1 div text is not `wrapping` (without space in between) so that div is going out of `viewport` so you are getting that `horizontal scrollbar`. So to avoid that wrap your text eg. `word-wrap: break-word;` use this `css property` where your text is going out.

[image]